Joining streams and calculate on interval between streams
So I need some advice on how to do this. I have two streams:
stream_1

node_id
price
timestamp

stream_2

node_id
value
timestamp

these two streams are independent of each other, only the node_id is shared. I would like to join the streams together by node_id, then for each interval (that can be weeks or longer, but usually minutes) I would like to calculate price x value x delta_t (where the delta_t is the amount of seconds between the start of the interval and the end of the interval).
What is the best way to achieve this?
I tried Kafka Streams using JoinWindows.ofTimeDifferenceAndGrace but this needs a duration, but the corresponding message might be very late.
I also tried KSQLDB using a stream-stream join (using within), but then it calculates all permutations between two timestamp, but I only need to calculate it once per interval.
I also tried to use a stream-table join with LATEST_BY_OFFSET of the stream2 in order to calculate it based on the latest available price per node_id, but this seems to add delays I think.
Here's a visualization:
stream1: ---x-----x-------x---  --> 3 messages
stream2: ------x-----x-------x  --> 3 messages

result0: ---I--I--I--I----I--I  --> 5 intervals

Do I need to use Apache Flink to use count-based windows (using 2 as the limit)?
Any pointers appreciated! Thanks.
